# MongoDB find query with compound index taking more than 300ms

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas, mongo-index

I have a MongoDB collection with 300,000 documents, and I'm experiencing slow query performance for a specific query. The document structure is as follows:

```
{
  "_id": 268621,
  "tenant_id": 1,
  "sub_tenant": "MAIN_SITE",
  "promotion_id": 42020,
  "property": "listing",
  "slot": 1001,
  "is_active": true,
  "priority": 0,
  "imageurl": "https://media12.ppl-media12.com/1687463343_schwarzkopf_professional_spa_essence-2596x836.jpeg",
  "m_imageurl": "https://media12.ppl-media12.com/1687463342_schwarzkopf_professional_spa_essence-1440x544.jpeg",
  "aspect_ratio": 3.10526,
  "m_aspect_ratio": 2.64706,
  "lp_url": "",
  "text": "",
  "tagged_pages": [
    1384569
  ],
  "segment": [],
  "mode_device": [
    "desktop",
    "mobile",
    "android",
    "iosapp"
  ],
  "group_id": 24,
  "start_date": 1687167000,
  "end_date": 1688149500,
  "last_updated_timestamp": 1687465021,
  "x_id": "listing",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2023-06-22T20:17:01.831Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2023-06-22T20:17:01.831Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

The compound index I'm using for the query is:

`property_1_slot_1_group_id_1_is_active_-1_tagged_pages_1_tenant_id_1_sub_tenant_1_start_date_1_end_date_1`

Here's an example of the query I'm running:

```
db.collection.find({
  "is_active": true,
  "property": "landing_pages_widget",
  "slot": 6010,
  "tagged_pages": 24005,
  "mode_device": "android",
  "group_id": 2,
  "start_date": { "$lte": 1688487854 },
  "end_date": { "$gte": 1688487854 },
  "tenant_id": 1,
  "sub_tenant": "MAIN_SITE"
})
```

The problem is that this query is sometimes taking more than 300ms to execute in case of high throughput, but when i execute single query in compass, response time was fine. I have used the explain() method in MongoDB compass to analyze the query, and it seems to be utilizing the compound index. Here are the results of the explain():

```
{
 "stage": "IXSCAN",
 "nReturned": 0,
 "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
 "works": 8,
 "advanced": 0,
 "needTime": 7,
 "needYield": 0,
 "saveState": 0,
 "restoreState": 0,
 "isEOF": 1,
 "keyPattern": {
  "property": 1,
  "slot": 1,
  "group_id": 1,
  "is_active": -1,
  "tagged_pages": 1,
  "tenant_id": 1,
  "sub_tenant": 1,
  "start_date": 1,
  "end_date": 1
 },
 "indexName": "property_1_slot_1_group_id_1_is_active_-1_tagged_pages_1_tenant_id_1_sub_tenant_1_start_date_1_end_date_1",
 "isMultiKey": true,
 "multiKeyPaths": {
  "property": [],
  "slot": [],
  "group_id": [],
  "is_active": [],
  "tagged_pages": [
   "tagged_pages"
  ],
  "tenant_id": [],
  "sub_tenant": [],
  "start_date": [],
  "end_date": []
 },
 "isUnique": false,
 "isSparse": false,
 "isPartial": false,
 "indexVersion": 2,
 "direction": "forward",
 "indexBounds": {
  "property": [
   "[\"landing_pages_widget\", \"landing_pages_widget\"]"
  ],
  "slot": [
   "[6010, 6010]"
  ],
  "group_id": [
   "[2, 2]"
  ],
  "is_active": [
   "[true, true]"
  ],
  "tagged_pages": [
   "[24005, 24005]"
  ],
  "tenant_id": [
   "[1, 1]"
  ],
  "sub_tenant": [
   "[\"MAIN_SITE\", \"MAIN_SITE\"]"
  ],
  "start_date": [
   "[-inf.0, 1688487854]"
  ],
  "end_date": [
   "[1688487854, inf.0]"
  ]
 },
 "keysExamined": 8,
 "seeks": 8,
 "dupsTested": 0,
 "dupsDropped": 0
}
```

Can anyone help by identifying what went wrong here?

Comment: Looks like the query is able to efficiently use the index, at least with the sample values provided. Is there a different set of query predicate values that are problematic? If the commonality for the slowness is that it is only when there is high throughput then this query may be the victim rather than the cause of the problem. Do you have a log entry or profiler entry showing one of the slow executions?

Comment: Can you add some detail to what you mean by "in case of high throughput"?